# Flutter Riverpod always one state behind / delayed

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, state-management

I have a drop-down where I can select several items. I am using a StateNotifier because the logic is a little bit too complicated for a simple StateProvider. I have a model class with attributes I want to fill e.g.

```
Class ReportError {
Name;
Code; 
Png;
...
}
```

So here is my problem:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final selectedValue = ref.watch(fillErrorModelProvider).selectedTool; //here I watch at my state, here I think is my problem
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        //..Here is my drop-down on changed
        onChanged: (value) {
          ref.read(fillErrorModelProvider.notifier).setToolName(value!);
                                  print(selectedValue); // and this is always one behind. So when I select cat, it says null, then I change to dog, it says cat.
        },
      ),
      //...
    ],
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? According to the documentation I thought I have to do this Variable = ref.watch(provider) directly under the build method.
When I change the print statement to the ref.watch directly, everything works fine.
My provider stuff:

```
final fillErrorModelProvider = StateNotifierProvider<FillReportBugModelNotifier, ReportBugModel>((ref) {
  return FillReportBugModelNotifier();
});
class FillReportBugModelNotifier extends StateNotifier<ReportBugModel> {
  FillReportBugModelNotifier() : super(ReportBugModel());

  void setToolName(String selectedTool) {
    state = ReportBugModel().copyWith(selectedTool: selectedTool);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the way it works.  During the build, you're reading the current value with watch.  The onChanged runs *after* the build is finished when the event occurs, and that runs the setter with the new value.  That will trigger a new build, which should have the new updated value.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz and why isn't it the correct value and always behind when it should work ? :D

Comment: @FabianM see my answer that explains the timeline of what happened. The behavior you wrote in this question is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

This is the timeline of what happened:

1. At the first widget build, the `build` method is called. The value of `selectedValue` is now `null`. The `onChanged` callback is **not** called yet.
2. User selects a dropdown item. The `onChanged` callback is called, executing 2 lines: 1) The one that call `setToolValue` that (I assume) modify the notifier state to `value` (which is *cat*), and 2) the one that prints the current `selectedValue`. Since this happens in the same scope of the current build (which is the first build mentioned in step 1), and no other build call has happened yet, so the value of `selectedValue` is `null`.
3. Since in the previous step the notifier value is changed to *cat*, the widget rebuilds by calling the `build` method again. This happens because you watched the provider by having a `ref.watch` call inside the `build` method. Now the value of `selectedValue` is *cat*.
4. When the user selects a dropdown item again, selecting the item *dog*, now the `onChanged` callback is called. The same thing happens as in step 2, in which the notifier state changed to *dog*, and the `selectedValue`, which currently holds the value of *cat*, is printed.
5. Since the notifier state changed in the previous step, the `build` method is called again. Now the value of `selectedValue` is *dog*.

Answer (score -2):

FYI: Idk what happened, but it works now after a night. Maybe the night fixed the issue :D
But this approach must be correct, so idk what was wrong, I didn't change the code.

Comment: What's "fixed"? Because the code in your snippet should work like the one mentioned in the question. If it works like the one you're expecting, then surely there are some problems you're not aware of.